# how to add fb profile link in laravel

Tags: laravel, hyperlink

```
<a href="{{$item->linkedin}}">
    <img src="img/linkedin.png" height="30px" width="30px" class="p-1" alt="">
</a>
```

In laravel blade following code result :

```
<a href="https://testb2b.large-it.com/linkedin.com/sahin">
    <img src="img/linkedin.png" height="30px" width="30px" class="p-1" alt="">
</a>
```

But I need

**"https://www.linkedin.com/sahin"**

instead of

**"https://testb2b.large-it.com/linkedin.com/sahin"**+

controller :

```
public function searchData(Request $r) 
{
    $data['common'] = $this->commonFunc();

    $data2 = DB::table('personals')
            ->join('companies', 'personals.companyId', 'companies.id')
            ->get();

    return view('frontend.dashboard2')->with(['data' => $data, 'data2' => $data2]);
}
```

Comment: Where does `$item->linkedin` come from, post your controller or model and any related accessor please.

Comment: Why controller and model is need to post ? Because $item->linkedin does not provide error.

Comment: Because whatever is in ```$item->linkedin``` is the root of your issue.

Comment: because it's unclear that what is its real value and where it comes from!

Comment: I updated th post

Comment: facebook, linkedin, all the same. That code does not deliver `$item` to the view, please paste the relevant code. One guess: whereever `linkedin.com/sahin` comes from is missing the protocol, change it to `https://www.linkedin.com/sahin`

Comment: How are you saving/storing the value of `linkedin`? Is the value saved as "`https://testb2b.large-it.com/linkedin.com/sahin`" in the database?

Comment: My problem fixed by @Kerbholz solution. Thanks